# How do I open multiple .json files at once that contain test cases?

Tags: python, json, testing, automated-tests

This is sample code that works for one json file. I need to load credit.json, housingP.json , mood.json , churn.json inside testSplited folder.

```
def load_test_params():
    with open(filePath + '/testsSplited/churn.json') as json_file:
    
        data = json.load(json_file)

        assert len(data['tests']) > 0
        test_params = data['tests']
        return test_params

TEST_PARAMS = load_test_params()
```

Answer (score 0):

Would be better to use the following pandas trick

```
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = pd.read_json (r'sequencesHost.json')
```

Answer (score 0):

This works using a for loop

```
def load_test_params():
    json_path = filePath + '/testsSplited/'
    json_list = [f for f in os.listdir(filePath + '/testsSplited/') if f.endswith('.json')]
    for i in json_list:
        with open(filePath + '/testsSplited/'+ i) as json_file:
            data = json.load(json_file)
            assert len(data['tests']) > 0
            test_params = data['tests']
            return test_params
```